# Returning items as they come in Python

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am not quite sure I am using the correct terminology but I would like to have access to items being returned by my function before the function finishes. For example, I am working on a Django project where I have a function that scrapes a cooking website, and returns what recipes you can cook based on the ingredients that you have.

The function works as expected but it takes a very long time. I would like to present users with the recipes that they can cook as they are found, instead of them having to wait for the entire function to run and thus the webpage to load.

I've pasted the relevant code below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
def give_recipe_from_ingredients(pantry_items):

    for link in get_recipe_links():
        current_ingredient_list = []
        can_cook = True
        grab_from = link
        grab_page = urllib.request.urlopen(grab_from)
        grab_soup = BeautifulSoup(grab_page, 'html.parser')

        rec_title = grab_soup.find('h2', attrs={'entry-title'})
        title = rec_title.text.strip()

        for ingredient in grab_soup.find_all('span', itemprop="name"):
            ingredient_strip = ingredient.text.strip()
            current_ingredient_list.append(ingredient_strip)


        for item in pantry_items:
            for ingredient_in in current_ingredient_list:
                if str(item) in ingredient_in:
                    if title not in recipes_you_can_cook:
                        yield title
                        #recipes_you_can_cook.append(title)




    #return recipes_you_can_cook
```

Edit- added my views.py file to reflect my use of yield above.

```
views.py

@login_required
def pantry(request):

    ingredient_list = Ingredient.objects.order_by('-name')[:]

    my_generator_instance = give_recipe_from_ingredients(ingredient_list)

    for recipe_name in my_generator_instance:
        print(recipe_name)
        recipes_you_can_cook.append(recipe_name)

    context_dict = {'ingredients': ingredient_list, 'recipes': my_generator_instance}


    return render(request, 'project/pantry.html', context_dict)
```

Comment: Have a look at [yield and generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)

Comment: @danielu13 thanks a ton! That worked like a charm for the function, however my URL is still not loading until the whole function completes. I've added my new view for it. Any suggestions?

Comment: I would try to load the page without the dynamic data your function is yielding and somehow connect to JS to load that as it comes in. I'm not really all that familiar with web dev though, so I'm not completely sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [StreamingHttpResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#django.http.StreamingHttpResponse). Note that your web server might still buffer the entire response before sending it to the client. I've noticed that nginx by default does this (but may be configurable), whereas apache by default sends the response as it comes in from the backend.

If you choose to return short responses updated through JavaScript, I believe [django-channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is the way to go, though I'm not certain (never used it, but it's quite fashionable).